# Can't get Azure AD B2C to work with Xamarin Forms

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have an **Azure AD B2C** tenant configured that I will use to authorise users from our **Xamarin Forms** app. I've configured the Azure tenant by adding the application as in the screenshot.

[image]

I have created a SignUp-SignIn policy for the app.

I have added the *Microsoft.Identity.Client* nuget package to the shared project of the app and based my code around this sample on [Github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native) and I am using MSAL2.0.

The values I am using are as follows:

```
    public const string Tenant = "myappname.onmicrosoft.com";
    public static string ClientId = "123456-1dda-4dba-9913-wsedfcrft554";
    public static string SignUpSignInPolicy = "B2C_1_MyPolicyName";
    public static string AuthorityBase = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Tenant}/";
    public static string Authority = $"{AuthorityBase}{SignUpSignInPolicy}";
    public static readonly string CustomRedirectUrl = $"msal{ClientId}://auth";
```

This gives me the Authority *https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/myappname.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_MyPolicyName*

In my code I create an instance of the *PublicClientApplication* class to allow the app to communicate with the Azure tenant as follows.

```
return new PublicClientApplication(ApplicationConstants.ClientId, ApplicationConstants.Authority)
    {
        RedirectUri = ApplicationConstants.CustomRedirectUrl
    };
```

I currently have two users setup in the tenant, but when I try to get a list of users it is always empty.

```
IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await AuthenticationService.PCA().GetAccountsAsync(); // always empty
```

I have tried several different combinations for the *Authority* value but none of them work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Here is a sample maybe can help you .https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native

Comment: The GetAccountsAsync is to fetch accounts from your cache. You should be first doing a succesfull GetTokenAsync call before you can fetch the account from the cache. This call will however not give you all user accounts which are registered on Azure B2c.

Comment: That example is identical to the one I've already been using https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native

Comment: @ChristiaanV Let me give that a try. Is there a function that returns all the accounts from Azure  B2C?

Comment: I'm not aware of a function in the library. I think you should first get an access token for an account that has rights to get the list of users and than use the Graph API to get the users https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-operations-overview?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I think my understanding of the authentication workflow is wrong. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Looking at the examples on Github the code firstly calls GetAccountsAsync() to acquire the accounts from the cache, finds a matching account for the specified policy, then calls AcquireTokenAsync() to acquire a token. All the examples follow the same flow. So I would expect GetAccountsAsync() to be returning accounts. In my case, nothing is ever returned.

Comment: GetAccountsAsync would have 1 or more accounts indeed if you have a succesfull authentication. Which platform are you testing on? As for Android and iOS there are some specifics which you should add to make it work.